# Inserting "NULL" or "NOT NULL" into ASP.NET parameterized queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I have an asp DropDownList that is used to filter database results. One of my filters is used to check if a column is NULL or NOT NULL:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="activeFilter" CssClass="form-control"  AutoPostBack="false" >
  <asp:ListItem selected="True" value="">-- Filter By Active/Inactive </asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem value="NOT NULL">Active</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem value="NULL">Inactive</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I then try to insert it into a parameterized query like so:

```
//called from another method

string query = ".... AND Status=@statusFilter ...."
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusFilter", statusFilter.SelectedValue);

//other stuff, make sql call
```

This process works for other filter values, something like

```
"... AND Name=@nameFilter ..."
```

Where nameFilter might be "John", "Tim", "Amy", etc. so I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that NULL and NOT NULL shouldn't actually be strings. Any easy solution for this? I see I can add DBNull.Value but what about NOT NULL?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Sorry everyone, I made a mistake in my first post - I copied the wrong query string. My query string is actually

```
"... AND Date_Completed IS @activeFilter ..."
```

I know I cant say Column=Null, so again I apologize. I'm going to run through the suggestions right now and update everyone.

**EDIT 2:**
Okay so the issue is that you cannot treat NULL / NOT NULL as parameters. I was hoping I could use it as a parameter as I had a number of utility functions to generate the final query based on a many different filters. Ultimately, this did not work, and I needed to alter my methods and insert the entire " IS NULL " or "IS NOT NULL" directly using an If/Else block.

Comment: You may be passing a `NULL` value but the query doesn't work. `NULL` in SQL means an Unknown value. The result of comparing Unknown to Unknown is itself `Unknown`. That's why `Name=@nameFilter` will *always* fail if `@nameFilter` contains a NULL

Comment: are you talking about DBNull? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.8
and anyway what kind of value is `NOT NULL` ? perhaps a bool column would be more useful in this case

Comment: You need two queries here, and an `if` statement to choose the right one, you can't use a parameter. Also, you should not be showing words like `null` to users, that's confusing UI.

Comment: Also relevant: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` are expressions, not values. If you want to check whether `Name` is null you'll have to write `NAME IS NULL`. If you want to see whether the name matches the parameter or is null itself you'll have to write `WHERE NAME IS NULL OR NAME = @nameFilter`

Comment: Thanks guys, I have it working now. See my edit, but it was ultimately solved using an if/else and updating the query manually, like @DavidG suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work like everyone says in the comments. 
You can do an If to see the value selected and in the sql query you can use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL. Something like below:

```
if (statusFilter.SelectedValue == "NULL"){
   string query = ".... AND Status IS NULL...."
}
else{
   string query = ".... AND Status IS NOT NULL...."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, You can't do `= null` nor can you parameterize `is null` or `is not null`.

This doesn't mean, however, that it can't be solved - something like this will do the trick:

```
...AND (Status = @Status OR 
    (Status IS NULL OR @Active = 'NULL') OR 
    (Status IS NOT NULL AND @Active = 'NOT NULL') 
)...
```